# Java Method Creating Extra Input Line - How Do I Get Rid of It?

Tags: java

I know where my problem is, and I know why I have a problem. I simply do not know how to fix it. My assignment is to have 6 or more methods, two of which accept input, two which calculate off the input of one method and then it needs to loop. I have the loop down, I just have this extra line that it wants me to input my number again. I don't know why. I have included my output so you can see where I need to get rid of an extra line and my 4 methods that seem to be causing me all my trouble.

My output now:

debug:
Welcome to the loan Round Object Calculator

This program will calculate the area of a circle 
   or the volume of a sphere.

The calculations will be based on the user input radius.

Enter C for circle or S for sphere: S
Thank you.  What is the radius of the sphere (in inches): 45.9

And again, because I could not figure out how to fix my methods. 45.9

The volume of a sphere with a radius of 45.9 inches is 405066.816 cubic inches.

Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N): Y
Enter C for circle or S for sphere: C
Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): 12.9

And Again, because I could not figure out how to fix my methods. 12.9

The area of a circle with a radius of 12.9inches is 522.792 inches.

Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N): n
Thank you for using the Round Object Calculator. Goodbye. 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 34 seconds)

I want to get rid of this line where I have added the note "And another because I could not figure out how to fix my methods.

Here is my entire code. Originally I only put the parts that were causing me problems. Why isn't the method holding my first answer and pushing it into the next method? How do I tell it to do that?

```
package circlesphere;


//Scanner is in the java.until package
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleSphere {


   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Step 1
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    intro();

   System.out.println();
   do{ 
     output(); 

} while (repeat());


}//end Main

/*
* A method definition consists of its method name, parameters, 
* return value type, and body.  The syntax for defining a method is as 
* follows:  
* modifier returnValueType methodName(list of parameters) { 
*   // Method body;
* }
*/

public static void intro()
{
     // Display the welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the loan Round Object Calculator ");
    //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle ");
    System.out.println("   or the volume of a sphere. ");
    //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The calculations will be based on the user input radius. ");

}
//Step 2
public static String takeInput()
{
    return input.nextLine();
}//end takeInput
//Step 2
public static double numberInput()
{
    return input.nextDouble();
}//end numberInput

//Step 2
public static char alphaInput()
{  
    return input.next().charAt(0);
}//end alphaInput

//Step 6
public static boolean repeat()
{
    char ask;

     //Ask if user wants to repeat
        System.out.print("Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N): ");
        ask = alphaInput();

    if ((ask == 'N') || (ask == 'n'))
    {                 
       //Good bye comment
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Round Object Calculator. Goodbye. ");

    return false;
    }
    else if ((ask == 'Y') || (ask == 'y'))
    {
    //Bug here. I have tried coping the if statement in main and that does
    //not fix my problem. It won't accept  calculateCS = printCircleSphere(shape);
    //again and just spits me back to my bool.

    return true;
    }
    return true;

}//end repeat
//Step 5
public static boolean output()
{
       char calculateCS;
       double radiusC, radiusS, areaCircle, volumeSphere;
       //There seems to be a bug here when tryig to run through the bool loop.
       calculateCS = printCircleSphere(); 

    if ((calculateCS == 'C') || (calculateCS == 'c'))
    {
        double radiusCircle = 0;

        System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
            radiusC = getRadius();  
            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("And Again, because I could not figure out how to fix my methods. ");
                //There is a bug here and I don't know how to fix it because I need to call 
                //getRadius() in printCircleArea() to calculate radius. I don't know how to 
                //make getRadius just fill in the other methods once I enter it.
                areaCircle = printCircleArea(); 
            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of " + radiusC + "inches is %.3f inches. \n", areaCircle );

            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();

    return true;
    }
    else if ((calculateCS == 'S') || (calculateCS == 's'))
    {

        System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the sphere (in inches): "); 
            radiusS = getRadius(); 
            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("And again, because I could not figure out how to fix my methods. ");
                //There is a bug here and I don't know how to fix it because I need to call 
                //getRadius() in printShpereVolume() to calculate radius. I don't know how to 
                //make getRadius just fill in the other methods once I enter it.
                volumeSphere = printSphereVolume();
            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();
                System.out.printf("The volume of a sphere with a radius of " + radiusS + " inches is %.3f cubic inches. \n", volumeSphere);

            //Blank Line
            System.out.println();

    return true;
    }
    else

    return false;
}//end output

//Step 2 - Accept input for Circle or Sphere
public static char printCircleSphere()
{   
    //Prompt the user for C for circle or S for sphere.
    System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: ");  
    //Allows user to input the variable.
    return alphaInput();

}//end printCircleSphere

//Step 2
public static double getRadius()   
{   
    //Allows user to input the variable.
    return numberInput();
}//end printRadiusS

public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793d;
//Step 3
public static double printCircleArea()
{
    double circle = 0;
    double radiusC = getRadius();//This is why I have a bug

    radiusC = Math.pow(radiusC, 2)  * PI;

    return radiusC;
}//end printCircle
//Step 4
public static double printSphereVolume()
{
    double sphere = 0;
    double radiusS = getRadius();//This is why I have a bug

    radiusS = 1.333333333 * PI * Math.pow(radiusS, 3);

    return radiusS;


    }//end printSphere


}//endclass
```

Comment: You should use System.out.println(..) instead of System.out.print(..) to make your I/O more readable...

Comment: It's hard to see the extra line in your output as it stands

Comment: Where is the code for the `alphaInput()` method?

Comment: @lucasvw - will go update to println(...).

Comment: @DaneBrick - And again, because I could not figure out how to fix my methods. 45.9 . If you look in my code, I have notes on where the bug occurs.

Comment: @lucasvw - did not orginally include it, because I was trying to limit how much code I included.
    //Step 2
    public static char alphaInput()
    {  
        return input.next().charAt(0);
    }//end alphaInput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments to a method in Java. For example:

```
public int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
int sum = this.sum(1, 2);
```

In your example you need to change your printCircleArea method to:

```
public static double printCircleArea(double radiusC)
{
    double circle = Math.pow(radiusC, 2)  * PI;

    return circle;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
if ((calculateCS == 'C') || (calculateCS == 'c'))
    {
        double radiusCircle = 0;

        System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
            radiusC = getRadius();  
            areaCircle = printCircleArea(radiusC);
                    System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of " + radiusC + "inches is %.3f inches. \n", areaCircle );
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: or better replace `Math.pow` with `radiusC*radiusC`, that would be more efficient

Comment: @niceman - I will take Math.pow out. This is my first class in Java and we just learned about Math.pow.

Comment: @KDGordon if this solved your problem, you can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @mrjuicy - sorry about that! I think it is now properly marked as answered.